# I am not able to import my class from one package to another package

Tags: java, android

I am having two different package.
here is the first package 
and name of the package is
`package com.restro.dextrocustomer;`...
 and class name is..

```
public class FirstPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Now my second package name is

```
package com.restro.dextrocustomer.Nav_Drawer;
```

and the name of second class is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener, FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

Now I want to import my first package into another package but i cant able to do it

Comment: Whats is the error you are getting?

Comment: you want to move one package file into another?

Comment: nothing but its not importing and not a single variable a m able to access

Comment: yes so can able to use its variable

Comment: no one can able to help me

Answer (score 0):

**import com.restro.dextrocustomer.FirstPageActivity;**

1. If you are using Android studio, just start typing "FirstPageActivity", It will automatically import it for you.
2. Make sure that you have saved the "FirstPageActivity" file (and the code is compiled).